# Is there a way to specify Build Action=None with nuspec?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

My company has an assembly versioning package that I've written in powershell and is distributed amongst my colleagues via our internal nuget feed.

There are a couple of template files which can be user-modified after the package in installed. These files are being included in the package which we generate via

```
nuget pack xxxx.csproj
```

We've done a little investigation and there files are not packaged when we change the `Build Action` to `None`.

Is there a way to tell nuspec to add the files to the project with `Build Action` set to `None`*?

Alternatively is there a way to tell `nuget pack` to not include certain files in the package in generates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nuget pack` will ignore any files or folders that start with period/full stop. So one easy way would be to rename your template files or the folder they are located in to start with a period/full stop if possible.

Answer (score 6):

1. NuGet pack has an Exclude parameter that can be used to filter out files that you don't want in your package.
2. If you want to include files that are auto excluded from your project then you need to add a nuspec to your project and add a  element that includes that file.

More information here:
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#From_a_project
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Pack_Command

Comment: good answer (obviously since you wrote it!), but the Danny's answer proved easier to implement for us. Thanks.